# Testing non‐browser‐based https clients for Poodle

Tags: http, client

I have a command line tool that can download any URLs like`wget` *(only for vcs systems)* but not it’s source code, how can I test if it is vulnerable to POODLE?

There are lot of online automated tools for testing if a web server or a web browser is vulnerable to POODLE.

But as my program is command line only, how to check if it supports SSLv3 over http?

Comment: check out my answer here: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/128009/6253

Comment: @schroeder : as the tool fails to get an http response, the answer is the same whether it support sslv3 or the server isn’t an http server *(it says `failed to clone the repository, try an another url`)*. If the http server doesn’t contains any resources, it would reply`there isn’t any repositories host there`on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command line tools shouldn't be vulnerable to [POODLE](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/10/14/poodle.html).

The reason is that POODLE is a cross-domain attack where the attacker can send cross-origin requests to the vulnerable endpoint and then use their Man-in-the-Middle/eavesdropper position to read cookie data sent with the request.

> An attacker can run Javascript in any origin in a browser and cause
>   the browser to make requests (with cookies) to any other origin. If
>   the attacker does this block duplication trick they have a 1-in-256
>   chance that the receiver won't reject the record and close the
>   connection. If the receiver accepts the record then the attacker knows
>   that the decryption of the cookie block that they duplicated, XORed
>   with the ciphertext of the previous block, equals seven. Thus they've
>   found the last byte of the cookie using (on average) 256 requests.

That said, there are other vulnerabilities present in SSLv3 that mean an upgrade is recommended.

- e.g. [TLS1/SSLv3 Renegotiation Vulnerability](http://www.acunetix.com/vulnerabilities/web/tls1-sslv3-renegotiation-vulnerability)

Running an SSLv3 server is the best way to test it, as [Ángel points out](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/128073/8340).

Comment: So if I understand, if a server support both tls and sslv3, then there are no problems in my case, isn’t it ?

Comment: I would say yes, as long as weak ciphers are also disabled, and as long as renegotiation is disabled, or secure renegotiation is enabled. However, since there are always advancements within the SSL/TLS protocol, it would be wise to always work towards disablement of legacy versions - You never know when the next vulnerability will be found.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by finding out which SSL library it is using. I wouldn't be surprised if it used (maybe embedded) an old openssl version, in which case there would be a number of vulnerabilities to take into account that could be easily extracted, not just poodle.

As [pointed out by  schroeder](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/128009/49489), you could launch a webserver that doesn't speak anything newer with:

```
openssl s_server -no_tls1 -no_tls1_1 -no_tls1_2
```

But it is much easier to attempt retrieving 
https://sslv3.dshield.org/vulnpoodle.png which is part of the https://www.poodletest.com/ test

`sslv3.dshield.org` is a server which only speaks ssl3. Thus, if your tool is able to retrieve it, it supports SSL3 in the configuration you are using.

Comment: I forgot about the png grab. That would make for a good POODLE test.

Comment: @schroeder I _knew_ there were purposefully misconfigured test servers out there for SSL3. Was lucky finding this quickly :)

Comment: heemmmm looks like I would need a web server.

Comment: @user2284570 sslv3.dshield.org is a public web server  you can use.

Comment: `sslv3.dshield.org is a server which only speaks ssl3`and that use starcom as a ca. which is not trusted by the tool *(yes I can’t modify the tool’s ca store)*.

Comment: @user2284570 it doesn't matter that it _shows_ it. It only needs to _download_ it. You can try providing just https://sslv3.dshield.org/ although I'm not sure what it's there.

Comment: @user2284570 The server does use a valid certificate (although it doesn't provide the intermediate), see [ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=sslv3.dshield.org). It's possible that the error you are getting is in fact because that ssl3 is not supported.

Comment: @Angel : no, because it complains that starcom isn’t part of the trusted ca store.